Error EADDRINUSE: Address Already in Use when Running Angular SSR App
I have an Angular SSR application that works well initially. However, when I start my app with npm run dev:ssr, the app compiles successfully, but when I try to change something in my code,
I get the following error:
Compiled successfully.
./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:163
throw error;
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::65336
at Server.setupListenHandle \[as \_listen2\] (node:net:1904:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1961:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:2063:7)
at Function.app.listen (./node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
at run (./server.ts:159:10)
at deferred (./server.ts:164:1)
at __webpack_require__ (./webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
at fn (./webpack/bootstrap:38:1)
at O (./webpack/runtime/chunk%20loaded:23:1)
at __webpack_require__.x (./webpack/bootstrap:39:1)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1940:8)
at invokeTask (./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:33)
at runTask (./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:159:47)
at call (./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:483:34)
at apply (./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:472:48)
at data.args.\<computed\> (./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:950:25)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -48,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 65336
}

Node.js v20.18.0
A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.

I don't know what is causing this problem. I tried updating my Node.js to the latest LTS version and Angular to the latest version, but it still doesn't work.
Here are the versions I'm using:
@angular/cli: 18.2.5 
node: 20.18.0

package.json:

"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/core": "^18.2.5",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "^18.2.5",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.3.1",
"@angular/animations": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/cdk": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/common": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/core": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/localize": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/material": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/platform-server": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/router": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/service-worker": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/ssr": "^18.2.5",
"@material/snackbar": "^14.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^17.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
"@opentelemetry/api": "^1.8.0",
"@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.47.1",
"@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web": "^0.39.0",
"@opentelemetry/context-zone": "^1.25.0",
"@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-proto": "^0.52.0",
"@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http": "^0.52.0",
"@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "^0.52.0",
"@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.52.0",
"@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web": "^1.25.0",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
"@schematics/angular": "^17.2.3",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.1",
"angular-favicon": "^1.0.9",
"assert": "^2.1.0",
"async-hooks": "^1.3.1",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
"browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
"cli": "^1.0.1",
"correlation-id": "^5.0.3",
"crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
"express": "^4.18.3",
"express-winston": "^4.2.0",
"fs-web": "^1.0.1",
"https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
"keycloak-js": "^23.0.7",
"ngx-cookie-service-ssr": "^18.0.0",
"os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
"path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"rxjs": "^7.8.0",
"stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
"stream-http": "^3.2.0",
"tslib": "^2.6.2",
"typescript": "5.5.4",
"update": "^0.7.4",
"url-polyfill": "^1.1.12",
"uuid": "^9.0.1",
"winston": "^3.12.0",
"zone.js": "\~0.14.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/cli": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.5",
"@angular/language-service": "^18.2.5",
"@types/express": "^4.17.0",
"@types/jasmine": "\~5.1.4",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
"@types/node": "^20.11.24",
"browser-sync": "^3.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "\~5.1.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "\~7.0.0",
"karma": "\~6.4.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "\~3.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "\~3.0.2",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.3",
"karma-jasmine": "\~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
"ts-node": "\~10.9.2"
}

Can anyone help me, please?
UPDATE: I found a workaround for this issue, and it may help someone else.
I installed portfinder and imported it in my server.ts file like this:
'import * as portfinder from "portfinder";'
Then, I changed my run function to:
async function run() {
  const port = Number(process.env['PORT']) || 4000;

  try {
    const availablePort = await portfinder.getPortPromise({ port });

    const server = app();
    server.listen(availablePort, () => {
      console.log(`Node server listening on PORT ${availablePort}`);
    });

    server.on('error', (error: any) => {
      if (error.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
        console.log(`Port ${availablePort} is in use EADDRINUSE, retrying another...`);
        setTimeout(run, 500);
      } else {
        console.log('Server failed to start:', error);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error finding available port:', error);
  }
}

run();


Does this answer help you? I mean the obvious thing would be to change the port to a free one.

I already added an update to my question that seems like your answer. Thank you!
